# several different problems in one question

Tags: support, asking-questions

Some questions like ([How can I see/stop current running crontab tasks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313033/how-can-i-see-current-running-crontab-tasks)) have several problems in them.
I think it is better to ask them step by step. but I do not know it is legal to ask such questions in askubuntu or not. What should we do in facing to such questions?

Answer (score 1):

The moderators and commenters will bring the issue the the community's and the OP's attention. In the meantime, it is kind, and not incorrect, to answer the OP's questions as efficiently as possible. The reason such questions are frowned upon is that they are difficult to answer. The OP is at fault here, not the answerer. Feel free to answer such questions if you feel you can and want to go the extra mile, but you are not obligated to, especially since it may be edited later.

Comment: Although the same does not apply to duplicate, reappearing questions, such as this one. Those are better left alone because when it gets marked as a duplicate, the OP will go to the duplicate question for help.